# How can I convert these coordinates to decimal degrees

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, gps

We have extracted the following coordinate set from a Microsoft SQL database, but are unable to convert it to a coordinate system that makes sense. We know that the coordinates should be in Cape Town, South Africa.

Actual_GPS_Latitude: -122146844
Actual_GPS_Longitude: 66350481

Answer (score 2):

These latitude/longitude coordinates are expressed in milliarcseconds. Dividing them by 3,600,000 will convert them to the more standard form in degrees.

In this specific case, we obtain -33.929679°, 18.430689°, or 33° 55' 46.844" S, 18° 25' 50.481" E, near the University of Technology in Cape Town.